# fix firebase js module

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

I'm here for your help again after several failed attempts. I'm doing an amazon clone website to practice different skills. It was going well until the firebase portion. I've checked the official firebase site for JavaScript.

```
import firebase from "firebase";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCOCeYxc55AadYW4ODhyjrApehQQrbSfWM",
    authDomain: "fir-3a819.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "fir-3a819",
    storageBucket: "fir-3a819.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "198132761508",
    appId: "1:198132761508:web:a42c545f129e292889b731",
    measurementId: "G-R26ZHCCPQ4"
  };

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

I've done

```
npm unistall firebase

npm clear cache

npm i firebase@^4.8.0
```

originally I've done it by

```
npm install -g firebase-tools && npm install firebase && firebase login
```

The message in the terminal currently is

> Failed to compile.
> ./src/firebase.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users\Owner\amazon-clone\src'

Answer (score 0):

**First, run:**

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
```

**Then run the command**

```
npm install -g firebase-tools && npm install firebase && firebase login

npm install
```

**and then you can also run**

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: This was the comment when I first tried to run rm -rf node_modules

Comment: rm -rf node_modules
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What is your Operating System ? Linux ? You can remove manually node_moduels folder and package-lock.json and yarn.lock manually too.

Comment: I have Windows 10 laptop

Comment: You can install git. https://git-scm.com/download/win with git bash rm command will work.